# UISearchController issue swift ios

Tags: ios, swift

I've a tableview with a search bar on it. I can search and it displays the correct results. When, I click on cancel, my tableview got all the data on it which is good. What I'm trying to achieve is, while searching, if I hit the return button on the keyboard, and when my search bar is empty, I'd like to have my initial data displayed. Here's my code for searching.
Basically it's our the contacts address book works on iPhone.

Any help will be welcomed.

```
 func setupSearchBar() {
        searchController = self.addSearchBar()
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.delegate = self
        searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
    }
func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
        if count(searchController.searchBar.text) > 0 {
            tableData = MyCoreData().search(searchController.searchBar.text)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

func searchBarCancelButton(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchBar.text = ""
    self.resignFirstResponder()
    self.view.endEditing(true)
    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    reloadTableDataFromDB()
}

func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
}
```

Comment: Just put an else that deals with the `searchBar.text` being empty, and return everything.

Comment: do you mind giving an example. I tried to have a else part in this function updateSearchResultsForSearchController and then reloaded the tableview data but same result

Comment: In the else part, check to see what your data is. Is it empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your updatesearch function is missing a else part to return the default loaded data. Do this:

```
 func setupSearchBar() {
        searchController = self.addSearchBar()
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.delegate = self
        searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
    }
func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
        if count(searchController.searchBar.text) > 0 {
            tableData = MyCoreData().search(searchController.searchBar.text)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        } else {
        return self.reloadDataFromDB()
}
    }

func searchBarCancelButton(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchBar.text = ""
    self.resignFirstResponder()
    self.view.endEditing(true)
    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    reloadTableDataFromDB()
}

func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
}
```